# Why do we need Kleene Star when there is concatenation?

Tags: regular-languages

For an alphabet $A = \{ a_1, a_2..., a_n \}$, the set of regular langages $L_r$ on $A$ are recursively defined by closed union, concatenation, and Kleene star's operator. I understood that languages ($A^*$) and regular languages (a subset of $A^*$) are different. **Why do we need Kleene star, isn't concatenation enough for this definition?**

Very simple "proof" that should be obviously wrong:

If $X \in L_r$ a regular language on $A$, and $E \in X^*$ (if i'm right also $X^* \in L_r$) a word then we could write $E$ as $e_1e_2\dots e_n = e_1 . e_2 \ldots e_{n-1} . e_n$, with each $e_i \in X$. Then $E$ is explicitly constructible by concatenation.

I forgot $\epsilon$ but so just add a simple rule that allow $\epsilon$.
My intuition says that it has something to do with infinity, that Kleene Star allows infinite-lengh chains whereas concatenation doesn't. Is it that?

Comment: For the same reason we need while-loops in programming languages. If we can't iterate all programs will stop within a fixed number of steps.

Comment: @HendrikJan Something something recursion :) Which actually has an analogue in this context as well - CFGs allow recursion, regular expressions do not.

Comment: @orlp Agreed. I was comparing regular expressions to "sequence, selection, iteration" programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions without Kleene star define *finite* languages. You can prove this by induction on the structure of the regular expression. In contrast, $a^*$ is a regular expression which defines an infinite language.

We could try to define $a^*$ using concatenation and union:
$$ a^* = \epsilon + a + a^2 + a^3 + \cdots $$
Unfortunately, the required regular expression is *infinite*, which we do not allow (infinite expressions do make sense in some contexts, for example in [infinitary logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic), but not here).

Comment: +1. And not only *don't* we allow infinite unions in the definition of regular expressions, we actually *can't* do so -- or at least, that definition wouldn't be equivalent to the standard one -- because that would also allow languages such as $a^n b^n = \epsilon + ab + aabb + aaabbb + aaaabbbb + \cdots$ that are known to be non-regular according to the standard definition.

Comment: In fact, infinite unions could represent *all* languages.